# Как в wordpress добавить span в get_cat_name()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброе время суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить span в get_cat_name, в макете есть заголовок:

```
<h2><span class="red">С КЕМ МЫ</span> РАБОТАЕМ</h2>
```

Как в названии категории заключить первые слова в span, чтобы потом в стилях выделить их цветом.
Спасибо!

Comment: "Первые" - это сколько? Одно? Три? Восемь? Задайте вопрос так, чтобы не приходилось догадываться о ваших намерениях. И приведите, пожалуйста, ваш текущий код, вместе с `get_cat_name()`.

Comment: "Первые" - это те три слова которые находятся внутри </span> (С КЕМ МЫ) и которые должны быть красного цвета, а слово "РАБОТАЕМ" должно быть серым

Comment: Вот текущий код <div class="title-h2"><?php echo get_cat_name(4) ?></div>

Comment: А если в другом заголовке будет 7 слов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы собираетесь работать с многобайтовыми строками (русские символы), то надо использовать `mb_ereg_replace()` вместо `preg_replace()`

```
<div class="title-h2">
    <?php echo mb_ereg_replace('^((?:\w+\s+){3})', '<span class="red">\\1</span>', get_cat_name( 4 ), 'msri' ); ?>
</div>
```

Этот код выделяет три первые слова (см. `{3}`) из результата функции `get_cat_name()` и оборачивает их в span.

Answer (score 0):

wp-includes/category.php :

```
function get_cat_name( $cat_id ) {
    $cat_id   = (int) $cat_id;
    $category = get_term( $cat_id, 'category' );
    if ( ! $category || is_wp_error( $category ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $category->name;
}
```

Функция с коробки.. Можно написать свою функцию, можно изменить её с коробки - не знаю на сколько это корректно, честно говоря, с WP имел дело несколько раз, особо не вникал. Вот немного моих мыслей как можно это реализовать:

```
function get_cat_name( $cat_id ) {
    $cat_id   = (int) $cat_id;
    $category = get_term( $cat_id, 'category' );
    if ( ! $category || is_wp_error( $category ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    if ($cat_id == 4) {
        return get_custom_name($category->name,'[red]','[/red]');
    } else {
        return $category->name;
    }
}
function get_custom_name($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

P.S. решение далеко не лучшее, надо:

1. конкретным категориям где что-то выделить в название прямо вписывать "тэги", аля [red] в примере моём.
2. следить за id категорий, которым надо что-то выделить

В общем-то, костыль ещё тот, но может сами сделаете как положено. удачи

Comment: Спасибо, но его то не работает, пишет: "FATAL ERROR: CALL TO UNDEFINED FUNCTION GET_CUSTOM_NAME() IN E:\OPENSERVER\DOMAINS\FIN-KOLLECT\WP-INCLUDES\CATEGORY.PHP ON LINE 211"

Comment: @IgorZeleny, отредактировал, функцию не так назвал был, сейчас должно работать

Comment: Предложение править ядро WordPress - это очень, очень плохой ответ. Зачем это, когда можно просто провести манипуляции со строкой, которую возращает `get_cat_name()`?

Comment: @KAGG Design, а можно поподробнее про манипуляции со строкой, которая возвращает get_cat_name()

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ

Comment: @KAGG Design, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я вот нашел такой вариант

```
<div class="title-h2"><?php echo preg_replace("#^(\w+)(.*)$#ui", "<span>$1</span>$2", get_cat_name(4)); ?></div>
```

но там выделят только первое слово, а как сделать чтобы выделяло первые три слова не знаю